Lie group element corresponding to the Lie algebra lower operator
Consider $SU(2)$ for concreteness. We know that the lie algebra $\mathfrak {su}(2)$ has three generators $J_z, J_+, J_-$. Given a $J_z$ eigenstate $|J,m\rangle$, we can apply the lowering operator on it to obtain a lower weight $|J,m-1\rangle$. We can think of this lowering operation as some unitary matrix $U_J(g)$ which acts on the $SU(2)$-irrep labeled by $J$. My question is what is the group element $g\in SU(2)$ that corresponds to the lowering operation?

Raising and lowering operators are not elements of the Lie group, but of the Lie algebra. In your example the lowering operator would be $J_{-}$.

@VladimirLysikov Sure, but my question is what's the Lie group element that unitarily maps $|J,m\rangle\mapsto|J,m-1\rangle$?

There can be no such element. For example, consider the adjoint representation of $SU(2)$. The weight vectors are exactly $J_{+}$, $J_z$ and $J_{-}$, and there is no element $g \in SU(2)$ which maps $J_{+}$ to $J_z$ or $J_z$ to $J_{-}$ because they are represented by matrices of different ranks.

You have abused/misconstrued unitarity. Recall $J_-^\dagger = J_+$.

Even if the lowering operator $J_-$ belongs to the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, it is not an element of the associated Lie group $SU(2)$. Indeed, let's consider the operation $g : |j,m\rangle \mapsto |j,m-1\rangle$, i.e. an unnormalized lowering operator. Then, one has $g|j,-j\rangle = 0$, which implies that the kernel of $g$ is not trivial, meaning that $g$ is not invertible, hence $g \notin SU(2)$ in the end.
The moral of the story : even if the classical Lie groups/algebras are all subrings of square matrices, which may act on the same vector spaces in the end, and despite the fact that they are linked by the exponential map for instance, their elements have to be considered as different objects.
